# Owl Carousel 2 beta , jump to a specific slide

Tags: owl-carousel

I have implemented the Owl Carousel 2 in my website , I want to be able to jump to specific slide by using the Jumbpto helper provided like so ,

```
$('.btnJump').click(function(){
    $('#myCarousel').trigger('owl.jumpTo', 3)
  });
```

but it seems that the beta version doesn't have owl.jumpTo helper.

**anyhelp** ? at least for finding the documentation for the beta version

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.btnJump').click(function(){
    $('#myCarousel').trigger('to.owl.carousel', 3)
  });
```

Documentation can be found here: 
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html

Comment: but this animates to the slide.. how can I jump without animation?

Comment: I am also looking for a solution without animation.

Comment: It's sliding all carousle available in the page though I am using particular ID. Any idea?

Comment: Super G. Saved my time instead of surfing

Answer (score 8):

For Owl Carousel 2.x.x I try this if you want to jump to item 0 with animation

```
$('#myowl').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [0,0,true])
```

Comment: Weird..without `true` in there the items are out of sync. Its like it scrolls by page rather than by item.

Comment: It works, but in the official doc there are only two Parameter: `[position, speed]`, where from this third parameter came

Answer (score 4):

It's a shame this wasn't documented anywhere :/

`jumpTo` doesn't appear to be working in owl carousel 2, however you can use `to` and pass in an array of params. The first param is the slide, the second param is animation speed. Sending a 0 tells it to not animate at all.

`owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [3, 0]);`

Comment: Are you on the latest beta code? Seems to be working good for me, where `owl` is the jquery dom element of the carousel (`owl = $('.carousel')`)

Comment: I am working on the latest beta code. Not working for me :(, it still animates the change. Maybe because I use `animateOut: 'fadeOut'` ?

Comment: Setting the speed to 0 didn't work for me either, but setting to 1 does the job. You can't see any animation when it's that low.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //Initialize Plugin
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel()

//get carousel instance data and store it in variable owl
var owl = $(".owl-carousel").data('owlCarousel');

//Public methods
owl.next()   // Go to next slide
owl.prev()   // Go to previous slide
owl.goTo(x)  // Go to x slide
```

Answer (score 1):

For Owl Carousel v2.3.4 I found you need to do the following:

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel').data('owl.carousel');
owl.to(slide number[,slide speed])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the slide index to the .carousal function.

Try the below code :

```
$('.btnJump').click(function(){
    $('#myCarousel').carousel(3);
});
```